# Compile typescript into different paths

Tags: typescript

I've want use TS for node local modules. How can I compile base project into /dist, but local modules compile at their(module) path.
Or do not try do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use two different `tsconfig.json` files.  You can set up [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) so that you can build both parts of the project with a single `tsc -b` command.

On a tangent, if you have a `node_modules` directory with some modules that you compile manually, you are likely to run into problems if you try to install additional modules in the same `node_modules` directory using a tool such as `npm` or `yarn`.  You are better off creating directories outside `node_modules` for your custom modules and registering them as dependencies in `package.json` using local paths, or using `yarn` workspaces or similar features of other tools.